# Supplement for Vm2 js which can securely run untrusted code in languages other than Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, sandbox, node-vm2

I am trying to implement a Node js web app, a simpler version of which is that users submit code files in multiple programming languages like C++, Python, Java, Js etc and the output produced,is shown to them. However, I am unable to find a way in which I can run the code files so that my server does not get affected. I want a way where I can limit the threads to access my file stream and put timeouts to the threads. I came across npm's Vm2 but I guess it only runs JS code. Any help would be appreciated.